# Socket io connected users key value array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a list of connected users using key and value pairs. The key will be the connected user, when I received a message I want to emit this to the receiver and sender (to and from)
Now I'm stuck on the part where I want to add the new connected user. How do I add the user to the user to the array?

Second issue is the foreach is not a function

```
let connectedUsers: { [key: string]: Socket }

io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
  socket.on('USER_CONNECTED', (profile: Profile) => {
    connectedUsers !== undefined &&
      Object.keys(connectedUsers).includes(profile.userId) &&
      Object.assign(connectedUsers, { [profile.userId]: socket })
    console.log(connectedUsers)
  })

  socket.on('MESSAGE_SENT', (message: ChatMessage) => {
    connectedUsers.forEach(cli => {
      if (cli.key = message.to || cli.key = message.from) {
        cli.emit('MESSAGE_RECIEVED', message)
      }
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectedUsers` is not an array but an object, so you can't use `forEach` to iterate it.
The good news is that you don't need it!

When `connectedUsers` is populated  you can refactor on message function like

```
  socket.on('MESSAGE_SENT', (message: ChatMessage) => {
    connectedUsers[message.to].emit('MESSAGE_RECIEVED', message);
    connectedUsers[message.from].emit('MESSAGE_RECIEVED', message);
  })
```

To add a user to the object `connectedUsers` simply

```
 socket.on('USER_CONNECTED', (profile: Profile) => {
    connectedUsers = Object.assign(connectedUsers, { [profile.userId]: socket })          
    console.log(connectedUsers)
  })
```